# How could I sum from two different table details?

Tags: sql, join, group-by, sum

I have a problem I need to sum up the total balance which is in the Account table and total value is the loan which is in the Loan table also need to list all of them name which is on the Customer table.

With my solution it add together right but it double it the first row.

```
select c.CustomerName, 
sum(a.balance), 
sum(l.amount) 

from Customers as c 

left join Account as a 
on c.CustomerID=a.CustomerID 

left join Loan as l 
on c.CustomerID=l.CustomerID  

group by c.CustomerID
```

Comment: Explanation: If a customer has two accounts A1 and A2 and three loans L1, L2, L3 and you join them on the customer ID, you get six rows A1/L1, A1/L2, A1/L3, A2/L1, A2/L2, A2/L3, because accounts and loans are not further related. If you then aggregate these rows you consider each account thrice and each loan twice. What you want to do instead is join the account sum and the loans sum, so aggregate before joining. I hope this helps you understand the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple rows matching on each join, so you end up with the same amount being sumed more than once.

To avoid that, consider pre-aggregating in subqueries, then joining:

```
select c.customername, a.sum_balance, l.sum_amount
from customers c
left join (select customerid, sum(balance) sum_balance from account group by customerid) a 
    on a.customerid = c.customerid 
left join (select customerid, sum(amount) sum_amount from loan group by customerid) l 
    on l.customerid = c.CustomerID
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works for me. could you please explain why I need this aggregation? And when I need to use it this way. I am practising for an exam and there I won't have database to check it need to only write it. So how I know when I need to use this way? Many thanks

Comment: oh and also why do  I not need using 'as' after sum(balance) sum_balance?

Comment: @Laura: as explained, you have multiple rows matching in both tables. You can run your original query without aggregation and stare at the results to understand the issue better: `select * 

from Customers as c 

left join Account as a 
on c.CustomerID=a.CustomerID 

left join Loan as l 
on c.CustomerID=l.CustomerID `.

Answer (score 1):

Do separate join with aggregation :

```
select c.CustomerName, a.balance, l.amount
from Customers c left join
     (select customerid, sum(balance) as balance
      from Account
      group by customerid
     ) a 
     on a.customerid = c.customerid left join
     (select customerid, sum(amount) as amount
      from Loan
      group by customerid
     ) l
     on l.customerid = c.customerid;
```